# When Replacement doesn't matter (drawing marbles)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag contains black and white marbles $(X>0, Y>0)$. We are asked the probability of successfully drawing *a* black marbles and *b* white marbles $(a>0,b>0)$ in exactly $a+b$ draws. For what values $\{X,Y,a,b\}$ does drawing with or without replacement not change the probability of success? In other words, in what specific situations does replacement not matter? What is the smallest number of marbles in the bag to have a solution?

I've generalized the equations for the chances of success:

$$\text{w/o replacement} = \cfrac{\binom{X}{a}\binom{Y}{b}}{\binom{X+Y}{a+b}}\\
\text{w/ replacement} = \cfrac{\binom{a+b}{a}X^aY^b}{(X+Y)^{a+b}}$$

I've tested these equations with small values $\{1,1,1,1\}, \{2,2,1,1\},\{2,2,2,1\}$, etc. that are easily checked by hand, and they appear to hold true. What I have found is that drawing without replacement does not always give an advantage over drawing with, so I assume by IVT, as $n$ approaches infinity there will be some integer set where the probabilities intersect. The problem is I don't know how to proceed from here in finding a Magic Set other than with trial and error. A discovered answer would be easy to check, but I wouldn't know how to potentially find one other than brute force.

Comment: "What is the smallest number of marbles in the bag to have a solution?" One marble in the bag (or even zero) is the smallest. Generally, drawing one marble (or zero) will give the same result with our without replacement. But that's boring.

Comment: There must be at least $X\ge a, Y\ge b$ marbles in the bag.

Comment: IVT only applies to continuous functions, and marbles are discrete objects.  The specific case where replacement does not matter is the case that only one marble is chosen.

Comment: Yes. For replacement to be a factor, a+b must be >= 2, and both colors must exists in the bag.

Comment: As the number of marbles approaches infinity, the discreet addition of marbles becomes comparatively continuous. With the Sock problem from MindYourDecisions (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuqcnrtdUCc), this logic explains that some sock drawer exists such that the chance of pulling of matching pair is 50%, but not that any previous sock drawer can be added to to attain this property.

Comment: If you draw with replacement, every draw that takes $X:Y$ away from $a:b$ increases the probability that later draws will take you back towards $a:b$. Thus, drawing with replacement favours $X:Y$ near $a:b$. Given $a$ and $b$, on either side of $a:b$ there will be a cross-over point where the probablities are equal, but it will usually not be at integer values of $X$ and $Y$. In fact, considering the denominators full of different factors, it seems unlikely that there would be any coincidences beyond the trivial monochromatic case; but I don't immediately see how to prove this.